# Reproducir sonido conforme aparecen imágenes en un div, problemas para su reproducción continua

Tags: javascript, while, booleano, setinterval

Os muestro un código Javascript para un contador regresivo que reproduce un sonido coordinado con una cuenta atrás.

```
    function contador(){

        var segundos = 6; 
    imagen5='<img src="contadorNum5.png" alt="contadorNum5" />'
    imagen4='<img src="contadorNum4.png" alt="contadorNum4" />'
    imagen3='<img src="contadorNum3.png" alt="contadorNum3" />'
    imagen2='<img src="contadorNum2.png" alt="contadorNum2" />'
    imagen1='<img src="contadorNum1.png" alt="contadorNum1" />'
    imagen0='<img src="contadorNum0.png" alt="contadorNum0" />'

var cuentaAtras = setInterval(function(){
  segundos--;
switch(segundos){//voy mostrando en el div los dibujos correspondientes al segundo
  case 5:
  document.getElementById("contador").style.visibility = 'visible';
  document.getElementById("contador").innerHTML=imagen5;
  sonidosegundos1();
  break;
  case 4:
  document.getElementById("contador").innerHTML=imagen4;
  sonidosegundos1();
  break;
  case 3:
  document.getElementById("contador").innerHTML=imagen3;
  sonidosegundos1();
  break;
  case 2:
  document.getElementById("contador").innerHTML=imagen2;
  sonidosegundos1();
  break;
  case 1:
  document.getElementById("contador").innerHTML=imagen1;
  sonidosegundos1();
  break;
  case 0:
  document.getElementById("contador").innerHTML=imagen0;
  sonidosegundos2();
  break;
  case -1://cuando se alcanza esta cifra el indicador se oculta-
  document.getElementById("contador").style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

if(segundos < 0)
  clearInterval(cuentaAtras);

  },1000);
}

  function sonidosegundos1(){
  var sonido = new Audio("tick.wav"); 
  sonido.play();
} 
function sonidosegundos2(){
  var sonido2 = new Audio("tick2.wav"); 
  sonido2.play();
}
```

Fuera del script hay un div, que es donde sale el contador, el cual se oculta y sale según se inicia la cuenta o termina.

```
<div id="contador"></div>
```

-La conclusión es que quería que este efecto de sonido se produjera con el cambio de cada imagen, pero por lo que parece en Javascript no se puede hacer nada sin que exista una interacción del usuario con el navegador ya sea en forma de click, en forma de pulsación de tecla o cualquier otro tipo de evento (al menos por lo que he podido ver).

Lo curioso es que el error que produce cuando informa que el usuario no ha interaccionado antes *DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.* se elimina en el momento en que hacemos cualquier evento.

En mi caso este problema no se va a dar, porque este efecto se produce en un juego que implica que el usuario esté moviendo un cursor en forma de punto de mira antes de que el contador llegue al final, lo que permite que siempre se esté produciendo interacción, con lo cual a efectos prácticos no me daría error por la interacción continua del usuario (solo con detectar una pulsación del cursor, o que este está pulsado, ya no falla).

También planteo una pregunta:

Para el testeo simplemente llamo a la función contador para comprobar su funcionamiento, pero quisiera probarla en forma continua, es decir, que se produzca siempre. He intentado ejecutarla en un while o en un do while, o incluso varias veces, pero no he logrado que funcione de continuo (me explico, se ejecuta la cuenta atrás y termina, y luego al poco tiempo, o con la aparición de un True, volviera a producirse), no lo he logrado aún, me gustaría tener alguna opción.

Comment: Para repetir función la puedes hacer recursiva es decir solo debes llamarla dentro de ella misma ´case -1: contador()´

Comment: perfecto, hace exactamente lo que yo necesitaba y además se confirma mi teoría, que una vez que ha tenido lugar un evento nunca dará error, ya sea este una pulsación de tecla o de teclado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para repetir función la puedes hacer recursiva es decir solo debes llamarla dentro de ella misma.

En tu caso:
    case -1: contador()

Recuerda que eso se ejecutará por siempre si quieres ponerle un limite puedes agregar un contador y una condición cuando se repita la determinadas veces se detenga la recursividad saliendo de la función con `return`

Comment: Perfecto, pondré eso en práctica.